# Only first ID from table is displayed

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database table as followed:

[image]

Using the code below, I display all rows in the `text` column:

```
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM test");
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
  $replyid = $row['ID'];
  while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     echo'
     '.$row['text'].'
     <form method="post">
     <input name="testing" type="submit">
     </form>
     ';
  }
}
```

When the user clicks the submit button, the code below is supposed to display the `ID` corresponding to the column `text`. For example:

- If the submit button next to 'hello' was clicked, the number 2 should display.
- If the submit button next to 'adios' was clicked, the number 4 should display.

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['testing'])) {
    echo $replyid;
  }
  ```

My problem is that only the `ID` from the first row in the table is displaying. If the user clicks the submit button next to 'bonjour', the number 1 will display *(instead of 3!)*

Comment: You know you're not using the id in the form right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add hidden field to form with your value:

```
echo'
     '.$row['text'].'
     <form method="post">
     <input name="replyid" type="hidden" value="'.$row['ID'].'">
     <input name="testing" type="submit">
     </form>
     ';
```

and then display that value from form

```
if(isset($_POST['testing'])) {
  echo $_POST['replyid'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. That displays the `ID` as the value of the submit button which is not what I want to do. When the user clicks the submit button, I want the `ID` to then display.

Comment: Hello. While doing some testing on my site, I discovered that the user is able to change the `ID` through inspect element. What are my options to prevent this?

Comment: Everything what is in browser can be changed by user. The only way to secure website is checking in php if user have right to do sth with ID which he sent

Comment: If you will not add this ID in form you will not have information what ID user sent to you.

Comment: Why are you worry that he will change this ID? You are showing him anyway all IDs so what is the problem?

Comment: I suppose you're right. When I check to see if the button was clicked, I can use a query to see if the `ID` exists.

Comment: Exactly. As I said: every thing which is in browser can be changed by user and you must validate all data in php

Answer (score 0):

try like this, but I'm actually not very sure that this is what you want.

```
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM test");
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
  while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     echo'
     '.$row['text'].'
     <form method="post">
     <input name="testing" type="submit" value="'.$row['ID'].'">
     </form>
     ';
  }
}
```

and your echo command should look like this

```
if(isset($_POST['testing'])) {
  echo $_POST['testing'];
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['replyid']` is empty in this example. should be $_POST['testing']

Comment: @PootieTang: Because, It was copied from The First Answer.

Comment: And when you set value for submit button this value will be showed as a button 'text' which probably is not a right solution here.

Comment: @nospor - good point. he could have used <button> instead of input tho.

Answer (score 0):

**First and foremost, I'd always suggest using a PDO method rather than MySQL/MySQLi**

```
class Connection    {
    public function __construct()    {
        return new PDO('mysql:host=X;dbname=X', 'user', 'pass');
    }
}

$Con = new Connection;
$Con->Prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
$Con->execute();
foreach($Con->FetchAll() as $row)    {
    echo $row['id'] . '\n';
}
```

The above section of code shows the ease of basic SQL statements, for future notice you can also use the PDO `bindValue()` for secure Queries.

```
[...]
$Con->Prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = :paramhere");
$Con->bindValue(":paramhere", 1);
[...]
```

I hope this helped, you can find more on PDO and SQL from the below links:

[PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) 
[SQL Select Where Clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

**EDIT: In addition to best practice, you should use conditional statements where using HTML.**

```
<?php foreach($Con->FetchAll() as $row): ?>
    <div class="example"> 
        This is HTML, Your ID is: <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```